# Why am I getting a '.then is not function error'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, redux

I am trying to dispatch and call the function getUnaddedCartItems in my cart actions:

```
cartRedirect = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(getUnaddedCartItems().then((result) => {
        if (result.length === 0) {
            this.setState({unaddedCartItems: result}); 
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        Actions.cart();
    }));
}
```

I am able to get into my action and the break point hits at the first line but then for some reason won't move on to the the next line and immediately jumps back out!

[image]

And then I get the error.  I do not understand why it doesn't try to go into my async call.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix the error?

[image]

Comment: Does `getUnaddedCartItems` return a Promise, or should there me another ) after that call?

Comment: I'm thinking you are missing a `)` after the dispatch call and that you really want the then after the dispatch call and the results from `getUnaddedCartItmes` is returned.

Comment: getUnaddedCartItems is not returning a promise but some function that's return one

Comment: I tried having just the AsyncStorage call in the action without being wrapped in the dispatch call but then I get an error sayings that "Actions must be plain objects.  Use custom middleware for async ations" but I don't want to use any middleware.  I thought the AsyncStorage should be returning a promise.

Comment: Have you hooked up the thunk middleware? Actions which return functions only work with redux-thunk

Comment: No but I guess I'll look into it.  Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispatch the thunk action, then handle the returned promise.

```
this.props.dispatch(createMyThunkActionReturningPromise())
    .then(handleMyPromise)
    .catch(handleMyPromseError);
```

The problem is you are dispatching the promise, not the function (thunk action).